# Best way to switch tab ui on webpage, z-index vs display

Tags: javascript, performance, tabs, z-index

The usual way to show\hide block in html is switching it's display property. But in case of performance of rendering, wouldn't it be better to play with z-indexes?

http://jsfiddle.net/WawVH/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matter of preference really. Display:none removes the element completely, which I think it then is no longer a node in the DOM structure, thus saving memory. Someone correct me if I am wrong.

You could run into a problem with your implementation though if you have overflowing content.

http://jsfiddle.net/yeQfC/

But you could always just turn off overflow with

```
overflow:hidden;
```

in your .content CSS definition

http://jsfiddle.net/gF3JC/